# NoClassDefFoundError on org.jruby.Main

Tags: java, windows, jruby, hpricot

I'm trying to install the hpricot gem on my Windows machine using JRuby 1.4.0RC1. I'm trying to follow the advice to the related question (see -> [Installing hpricot for JRuby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726412/installing-hpricot-for-jruby/1323619#1323619)).

Per the answer's advice I pulled the git head of hpricot and from it's dir ran:

```
jruby -S rake package_jruby
cd pkg
sudo jgem install ./hpricot-0.8.1-jruby.gem
```

But when I run this I get the following NoClassDefFoundError:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jruby/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jruby.Main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: org.jruby.Main.  Program will exit.
```

Apparently my JRUBY_HOME\lib\jruby.jar is getting lost.

running jruby -v works fine, so I'm confused where my class path is getting messed up.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your jruby install isn't complete. Did you grab the `bin` or `src` dist? Check if `lib/jruby.jar` exists, make sure `bin/jruby` is in the same jruby location as `lib/jruby.jar`, and test `java -jar lib/jruby.jar -e "puts 'hello'"` to see if it's functional.

Comment: I think you're on the right track! I used the 'JRuby 1.4.0RC1 Windows Executable' to install JRuby. When I attempt java -jar lib/jruby.jar -e "puts 'hello'", I get the message: "Unable to access jarfile lib/jruby.jar". Do I have to specify JRUBY_HOME in the CP for each java execution or is there a way (or should the installer accomplish this) that I can make JRUBY_HOME inclusion the default?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: You may want to try the RC2 installer; I think there were some issues with the RC1 installer or the bat files that originally ran JRuby. Now that it ships with a jruby.exe, it may work correctly for you. If not, please file a bug at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY

Answer (score 1):

I suspect sudo does not inherit your environment variables. So JRUBY_HOME is gone. Try to add it to jgem profile.

Comment: how do you add JRUBY_HOME to the jgem profile? $JRUBY_HOME is echoed in my bash and Windows cmd sessions.

Comment: Do 'sudo jgem set' and check if it has the variable. If not, go to ~jgem (that it jgem home), find .profile file, and add the variable there.

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestions. Not sure if I'm able to do what you suggest. JRuby is coming up in the gem environment (see below). When I check out the installation dir, I don't see any file representing a profile. Pls see my 'answer' below for more context.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Windows. I'm not sure if JRuby 1.4 drops the 'j' prefix. jgem isn't recognized, but gem is. Regardless, when I gem environment I get:

```
C:\tmp\hpricot>gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2009-09-30 patchlevel 174) [java]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/jruby-1.4.0RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/jruby-1.4.0RC1/bin/../bin/jruby.bat
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/jruby-1.4.0RC1/bin/../bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-java-1.6
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/jruby-1.4.0RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "install" => "--env-shebang"
     - "update" => "--env-shebang"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org/
```