# Problem with jRuby in mingw / git bash shell

Tags: windows-7, jruby, mingw, msys

I'm having an issue executing jruby from the mingw git bash shell in windows. I downloaded the windows installer for jruby 1.6.2 and ran it without issue. If I open a new windows cmd shell it seems to work fine. I installed the rake and sinatra gems; used the irb. entering jruby -v gets:

```
jruby 1.6.2 (ruby-1.8.7-p330) (2011-05-23 e2ea975) (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.6.0_24) [Windows 7-x86-java]
```

However, when I open the git mingw bash shell and attempt to do anything with jruby I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jruby/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jruby.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: org.jruby.Main.  Program will exit.
```

I have made sure that the jruby lib directory is in the classpath.

Any other ideas?

**UPDATE:**
 I think the issue is the shell scripts that end up invoking the jar in the jruby bin directory.

The issue is that while msys can transform POSIX to Win paths for most things, but the script builds up strings on its own in order to pass classpath and other information to the jar.

It appears that this is where things are getting messed up. The scripts specifically have branches of code that deal with cygwin for this same reason. I attempted to force the scripts to to think that it was running under cygwin but unfortunately the scripts make use of the "cygpath" program to get the paths and that is not available in msys

Comment: Is this related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534977/noclassdeffounderror-on-org-jruby-main ?

Comment: I don't think so. It seems specific to msysgit/mingw Everything works fine in cmd. I think it must be some kind of pathing issue

Comment: also if I cd in ming to the jruby directory and do java -jar lib/jruby.jar -e "puts 'hello'" it works. Just have issues outside of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out is was indeed a "missing feature" of the bash scripts. I submitted a bug to the jruby jira and it was resolved

https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-5864

Note that as of the time of this writing that commit has not been part of the build that's available for download on the jruby web site. But the fix was quite simple.

Here is the commit: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/commit/8766f84b774ae5ae68204931bd4eab61b81a2056

All it is is adding the following to the uname case at the top of the jruby.bash file

```
MINGW*) jruby.exe "$@"; exit $?;;
```

Comment: It's in the newest binary distros now.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is, a mingw shell might not inherit all environment variables from the Windows environment.
So if a `java -jar lib/jruby.jar -e "puts 'hello` works within the jruby directory, then:

```
java -jar /full/path/to/jruby/lib/jruby.jar -e "puts 'hello
```

ought to work as well.
If not, carefully diff the two set of environment variables (normal DOS shell, where it works, and mingw shell where it doesn't)

---

It could also be as simple as a [difference of syntax for the classpath in a mingw environment](http://lists-archives.org/mingw-users/02483-help-with-classpath.html), as [illustrated in this thread](http://mingw-users.1079350.n2.nabble.com/Problem-with-paths-td6167145.html):

> Your problem is not that the path isn't being passed correctly; it is that you haven't allowed it to be passed at all.
>   As typed, your command line includes an unquoted semicolon; **in any Bourne compatible shell such
>   as bash, the unquoted semicolon acts first as a command terminator and then as a command separator**, so your command line becomes equivalent to the two separate commands:

```
$ java.exe -classpath .
$ $DIR hello
```

> [Caveat: I don't have a Windows box here; the following is untested]
>
> You need to quote the semicolon, AND (because you have now introduced a parameter which represents a path list in Win32 native format, so it will be exempt from translation, you need to ensure that `DIR` is ALSO defined as `DIR=d:/myClasses` NOT as `DIR=/d/myClasses`):

```
$ java.exe -classpath .\;$DIR hello
```

> OR, you need to specify the path list entirely in UNIX format, (i.e. **with a colon NOT a semicolon as the individual path separator**):

```
$ java.exe -classpath .:$DIR hello
```

Comment: It was a bug, I posted the fix as a answer. Thanks though, your answer put me on the right track.